# Can we get all the annotation views from MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any direct method or any suggestion on how to get all the annotations from the `MKMapView`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can access map's annotations using its `annotations` property. Getting views for all annotations may not be always possible as annotations that are not currently visible on the map may have no views associated with them, but for arbitrary annotation you can try to get a view using `-viewForAnnotation:` method.

So here how you can iterate through all map's annotations and try to access their views:

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations){
    MKAnnotationView* anView = [mapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
    if (anView){
       // Process annotation view
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a NEW set of MKAnnotationViews - not return the existing ones on your map.

Comment: ^ No, it won't create a new annotation. Original solution is correct.

Comment: Aneil, I suspect you're confusing the `MKMapView` method `viewForAnnotation` (which works correctly in Vladimir's example) with the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` (which creates annotations, but you never call directly).

Answer (score 5):

In swift 3.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation

        for annotation in mapView.annotations {
            let viewI = mapView.view(for: annotation)

            if !(viewI?.annotation is MKUserLocation){
                if annotation.isEqual(selectedAnnotation) {
                    viewI?.image = UIImage(named: "focus.png")
                    showLifeEventView(anotation: view) //did select a point on Map.
                }else{
                    viewI?.image = UIImage(named: "point.png")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That was awsome bro. . it saved my time. .